# gconf for lubuntu?

Tags: gnome, gconf, lubuntu

Does `gconf` have any affect on lubuntu-desktop config? Or does the "g" in "gconf" mean "GNOME", meaning that it's GNOME-only? Or am I missing something?

Reason I'm asking is because I made an edit in gconf for my trackpad, and it doesn't appear to be taking affect in lubuntu, only in GNOME.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The g in [gconf](http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/) does mean gnome. Because it is a gnome project it might not work in lubuntu. To change the touchpad setting in lubuntu see [lubuntu touchpad](http://lubuntu.net/tags/touchpad).

Answer (score 1):

Gconf is originally (and still is) a GNOME technology, but that doesn't stop other applications from using it. Probably however, the Lubuntu developers chose not to depend on gconf for their configurations (I've not found them to do so so far).

This however does not mean that only GNOME applications use gconf. For example, Avant Window Navigator uses it (optionally I believe), even though it can be run on anything (and is not GNOME specific).